# React: How to call react hooks inside the event handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code inside a react functional component. When I click the button and run the handler, an error occurs:
`Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

```
const handleClick = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(x); // this is wrong
};
```

I tried to search for the fix, someone suggests:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

const handleClick = () => {
  setCount(x); // setCount is ok, but I cannot set other dynamic states
};
```

However, my `count` state is dynamic and I cannot initialize all from start. When I use class components, it was easy.

```
// old syntax from class components
state = {
  count: 0
};

const handleClick = () => {
  this.setState({
    other_count: x
  })
};
```

How to achieve the same effect for functional components?

Comment: Can you post your package.json?

Comment: can you post your whole component

Comment: "react": "^16.9.0", "react-dom": "^16.9.0", "react-redux": "^7.1.1", "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1", "react-scripts": "2.1.8"

Comment: Is `other_count` a computed key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to use `state` dynamically, use `object` as `state`.

Keep in mind with the **immutability**.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ count: 0 });

const handleClick = () => {
  setState({...state, other_count: x });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use multiple states or an object in a single state.

First way:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const [otherCount, setOtherCount] = useState(0);

const handleClick = () => {
  // count is already available to you.. so update the other state
  setOtherCount(x);
};
```

Second way:

```
const [compState, setCompState] = useState({ count: 0, other_count: 0 });

const handleClick = () => {
  setCompState(prevState => { ...prevState, other_count: x });
};
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-bird-l97e4?fontsize=14) for the second way.

Comment: will it fail if I update multiple states from different functions? For example `state = { a: 1, b: 2 }` and `setState({ ...state, a: 10 })` `setState({ ...state, b: 20 })` from different async functions, any race conditions?

Comment: If you are updating in async functions, then you can use another way to update state. `setState(prevState => { ...prevState, a:10 })`

Comment: @5413668060 You can check this link as well. I have used setTimeout to test async kind of behaviour. https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-bird-l97e4?fontsize=14